# Get username client side

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an ASP.net web app which is being hosted on a server. This web application is my Outlook add-in. I want to get the username logged in to the Outlook application. The plugin does not load when I try to use impersonation. By default, the username should not require an authorization login. I have tried many methods but without success (disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication, User.Identity.Name etc.)

Can anyone assist with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable FormsAuthentication in webconfig

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

then you should set userName by

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);`

When the user submits the login form

you can reach the userName with `User.Identity.Name;`

Comment: This is web application not web forms. As I said - I don't want to have login form authorization.

Comment: I misunderstand u you can try this Call Application.Session.CreateRecipient (returns Recipient object), call Recipient.Resolve, read Recipient.Name property.

Comment: Melih I am using VS not VB.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use OOM from web applications. Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

You may consider using EWS or Outlook REST API, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.